# absolute smallest linux instance with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

This is not for a practical use but more a challenge. My teacher asked to create the absolute smallest linux ova that you can ssh to. He said last year the smallest was 4mb.

Any ideas or guidelines how i can beat this? From some reading i found tinycorelinux and this minimal linux thing https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal.

Thanks :)